# rigify shoulder is creating a really bad crease.. isnt collar bone supposed to be reactive?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, rigify

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
The shoulder doesnt move the collarbone at all. It just creases and looks terrible
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SvOunbZ_EAsWLOzpRwriw98oCuMoOv04/view?usp=sharing
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxJqz.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8B9w.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSadw.jpg

Comment: Please use the built-in method to add images to your question rather than making folks go to an external site! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post